I deploy project to Vercel but backend can't fetch data
I deploy project to vercel by project can't fetch data show error : GET http://localhost:3000/api/totalReserve net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
But localhost is work can fetch data
I try to setup next.cofig.mjs to allow cors
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
          },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            value:
              "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["images.unsplash.com", "plus.unsplash.com"],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;


Advice me please
Try setup config core in file next.config.mjs , setup in file project.json on folder vercel

Please provide client code as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Upon looking at the description.
I noticed that you were trying to send a api request to localhost on production.
Unfortunately, thats not how it works.
You have to fetch the actual deployed api URL.
Let me explain with the help of an example, your code must be:
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/totalReserve")

However, the same code won't work in production, in Production the code needs to be:
fetch("https://deployedurl.vercel.app/api/totalReserve")

My suggestions on what you can do in your code:

Case 1: If you are using nextjs api route on the same app, then you can simply set the code to:

fetch("/api/totalReserve")

This will work because it'll directly get the path of the current url.

Case 2: The api is built in a different app

For this, you can set a .env variable like NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL, and you can fetch by using
fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/totalReserve`)

If it doesn't resolve your issue, kindly add your code in the question and I'll surely assist you!
